# Initialize a TypedDict and fill keys & values later

Tags: python, mypy, typeddict

I have a dict with of which the types of the keys and values are fixed. I want to define the types in a `TypedDict` as follows:

```py
class MyTable(TypedDict):
    caption: List[str]
    header: List[str]
    table: pd.DataFrame
    epilogue: List[str]
```

I have function that returns a `MyTable`. I want to define first an empty `(Typed)dict` and fill in keys and values.

```py
def returnsMyTable():
    result = {}
    result['caption'] = ['caption line 1','caption line 2']
    result['header'] = ['header line 1','header line 2']
    result['table'] = pd.DataFrame()
    result['epilogue'] = ['epilogue line 1','epilogue line 2']
    return result
```

Here MyPy complains that a type annotation for result is needed. I tried the this:

```py
result: MyTable = {}
```

but then MyPy complains that the keys are missing. Similarly, if I define the keys but set the values to `None`, it complains about incorrect types of the values.

Is it at all possible to initialize a `TypedDict` as an empty Dict first and fill in the keys and values later? The [docs](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/type_inference_and_annotations.html#explicit-types-for-collections) seem to suggest it is.

I guess I could first define the values as variables and assemble the `MyTable` later but I'm dealing with legacy code that I'm adding type hinting to. So I'd like to minimize the work.

Comment: Is there any reason why ``returnsMyTable`` does not just include one ``dict`` literal, assigning keys and values immediately?

Comment: Since the derivation of the values is rather complex, creating the `MyTable` in 1 line is infeasible. Like I wrote, I could first define the values as separate values but I'm dealing with legacy code that's been set up in this way. This works `result = MyTable(header=[''],caption=[''],table=pd.DataFrame(),epilogue=[''])` but seems rather unpythonic

Comment: I don't think we can really help you unless you clarify what the issue with "legacy code" is. The only general solution is to `# type: ignore` the issue if you know the result is correct.

Comment: With "legacy code" I simply mean a pre-existing codebase to which I'm adding type hinting. There is no issue with it, but other than adding the type-hints I want to make minimal changes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you might want here is to set totality, but I'd think twice about using it.

Quoting [the PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0589/#totality)

> By default, all keys must be present in a TypedDict. It is possible to override this by specifying totality. Here is how to do this using the class-based syntax:

```
class MyTable(TypedDict, total=False):
    caption: List[str]
    header: List[str]
    table: pd.DataFrame
    epilogue: List[str]

result: MyTable = {}
result2: MyTable = {"caption": ["One", "Two", "Three"]}
```

As I said, think twice about that. A total `TypedDict` gives you a very nice guarantee that all of the items will exist. That is, because MyPy won't allow result to exist without "caption", you can safely call `cap = result["caption"]`.

If you set total=False, that guarantee goes away. On the assumption that you're using your `MyTable` much more commonly than you're making it, getting the additional safety assurances when you use it is probably a good trade.

Personally, I'd reserve `total=False` for cases where the creation code sometimes genuinely does leave things out and any code that uses it has to handle that. If it's just a case of taking a few lines to initialise, I'd do it like this:

```
def returnsMyTable():
    result = {}
    result_caption = ['caption line 1','caption line 2']
    result_header = ['header line 1','header line 2']
    result_table = pd.DataFrame()
    result_epilogue = ['epilogue line 1','epilogue line 2']
    result = {
        "caption": result_caption, 
        "header": result_header, 
        "table": result_table, 
        "epilogue": result_epilogue
    }
    return result
```

Comment: Thanks. I agree that removing the totality requirement is undesirable (defeats the purpose of type-hints). Your last suggestion is what I meant with "defining the values as variables and assemble the `MyTable` later". As I said, the [docs](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/type_inference_and_annotations.html#explicit-types-for-collections) show that it's possible for regular `dict`s (`d: Dict[str, int] = {}`). But apparently not for `TypedDict`s.

Comment: That's correct. All that the regular dict notation is saying is that everything in `keys()` is a string and everything in `values()` is an int. MyPy isn't checking that your `d` will satisfy that once you put some stuff in it a few lines down. It's checking that it already does. There's nothing in keys or values which isn't a string or int (because there's nothing in keys or values!) and so it's legal.