# How can I get an error from python Typeddict?

Tags: python, typeddict

I've got the exactly same question as the one below which hasn't got any answer yet.
My environment is the latest Python 3.8.8 + windows machine.
Any idea? Thanks.

[TypedDict didn't raise unexpected key error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69414825/typeddict-didnt-raise-unexpected-key-error)

```
from typing_extensions import TypedDict

class SalesSummary(TypedDict):
    sales: int


def get_sales_summary() -> SalesSummary:
    return {
        "sales": 1_000,
        "country": "UK",
        "product_codes": 1,
        "dummy" : "dummy",
    }


print(get_sales_summary())
```

and get the return like this

```
{'sales': 1000, 'country': 'UK', 'product_codes': 1, 'dummy': 'dummy'}
```

Comment: @python_user Thanks for your comment! Then how can I detect a wrong input and return any error to reject that?

Comment: @python_user That's the trick!! thank you so much!!!

Comment: @python_user but then why does a parameter ```total=False``` exist? If it doesn't raise any error for a wrong type or format, it means nothing to create an object with the use of TypedDict though?

Comment: @python_user thanks for your quick turnaround! Does this probably explain what my point is? Thanks! - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65690783/initialize-a-typeddict-and-fill-keys-values-later